# Access native form properties that were overridden by field names?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

This is quite the vexing question, but please bear with me.
It's a well known feature of the javascript DOM that if you have a form field with `name="something"`, the form's javascript DOM representation will have a `something` property that is a reference to the field's DOM representation.

Now, if the field's name ("something") is equal to one of the form's native properties, it will take its place in the javascript object. For instance, for a form:

`<form id="Form"><input name="submit" /></form>`

we'll have:

`var s=document.getElementById("Form").submit; // s is the input`

instead of

`var s=document.getElementById("Form").submit; // s is the native submit function`

Is there a way to access the native property at all in a situation like this?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Just to clarify two points:

- I'd like to be able to access any property, not just functions
- I mean this as a general question. A logical solution would be not to provoke name clashes in the first place.

Comment: Could you just use onsubmit instead? Could be a way around the issue...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to access the native function if you have an input named 'submit.'  I *just* ran across this same topic in Chapter 11 of [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/) by John Resig and Bear Bibeault.  I think if anyone knows the ins and outs of JS and the DOM, it's them.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.getElementById("Form"))
```

It will use the native method and invoke it in the context of the element that's on the page.

Comment: Thank you. I'm tempted to accept this, but I'd like to see two things: 1) a hint at a portable way to access the prototype, 2) a way to access properties other than functions, which I fear is more tricky if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post this as an edit to Ivo's answer, but it was rejected. The message is cryptic, but if what they meant was that I added too much to the original, then I think it's wrong, since I was merely trying to complete it. If the reason was different, feel free to comment. With this edit I'd have accepted Ivo's answer,  but without it I think it is incomplete.

Ivo's answer works for native functions, but it isn't applicable to attributes. For attributes it seems there is a number of ways, all similar but none of them perfect, to retrieve the value. I've tested the following on **IE9**, which is all I have available here, but http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes indicates the behaviours are generally, if not completely, consistent:

```
form.attributes['name']       // node representing the 'name' attribute

form.getAttribute('name')     // input with name="name"

form.attributes['submit']     // null

form.getAttribute('submit')   // input with name="submit"

form.attributes['onsubmit']   // node representing the 'onsubmit' attribute, 
                              // whose value is a string

form.getAttribute('onsubmit') // input with name="submit"
```

Based on this, it seems that (again, notice I didn't test it thoroughly):

- For value attributes, one may use the `attributes['attribute name']` approach, which should work down to IE6.
- For prototype functions, one may use the `prototype.fn.call` approach
- For function attributes, maybe one can retrieve the source code of the attribute and use that, but I'd rather not have to.
- Since `getAttribute` seems to return the named input instead of the attribute, at least in IE, it seems pretty useless.

Answering my original question, it looks like in the majority of cases there will be ways to access the properties, but it will depend on the property and eventually the browser.